File Delete Not Working on .NET MAUI (for Android Platform)
I have a code like this:
string filePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "test.jpg");

if (File.Exists(filePath))
{
    Debug.WriteLine("File Exist!");

    try
    {                
       File.Delete(filePath);           
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
       Debug.WriteLine("Exception!");       
    }   
}
else
{
    Debug.WriteLine("File not exists!");
}


if(File.Exists(filePath))
{
   Debug.WriteLine("File not deleted!");
}        


// Output: 
File Exist!
File not deleted!


I am writing an application for Android. I am trying to delete a file in the AppDataDirectory folder but I cannot delete it. I also do not receive any exception messages. I cannot understand this situation. (Although the AppDataDirectory folder does not require write permission, I have added the necessary permissions. Also, such a problem does not occur in the Windows application and the file is deleted). Can your help me with this issue? Thanks.
EDIT
I did some deep research on this. I think it's a problem with .Net Maui (.NET 8). (on Android).
My alternative solution was:
var file = new FileInfo(filePath);
file.Delete();


So the file can be deleted on Android too.

First of, the Path.Combine will not create the file if it's not existed on the android. So I used the FileStream to create it.
string filePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "test.jpg");
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
}

And then, the File.Delete(filePath) work well in my project. The output in my project:
// Output: 
File Exist!

And I have used the Device File Explorer in the Android Studio to check the result: The file will be deleted after File.Delete(filePath) excuted.
The environment I used:

Visual Studio 17.11.0 Preview 2.1
.Net 8.0
Test on both Android 10 emulator and XiaoMi physical device with Android 14.0


Yes, I was able to successfully delete my existing file this way. It's interesting that I only experience this issue on Android. Thx!
